# trying to do math, int object is not callable

Tags: python, math, first-class-functions

```
def square(x):
    int(x)
    return 2(x * x)

def my_map(func, arg_list):
    result = []
    for i in arg_list:
        result.append(func(i))
    return result

squares = my_map(square, [1,2,3,4,5])

print(squares)
```

i'm trying to pass a number to a function and have it print the result, i have a function for the equation `def square()`, and a function that receives the numbers and the function

I keep on getting this error:

> "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

I'm new to programming and was watching corey shaffer in YouTube and he wrote a program similar to this one. I started to play around with it, and now I'm stuck.

I would like the print statement to print out `arg_list(i)` and have I go through `def square(x)` and have that answer stored in result

Comment: What are you trying to do with `2(x * x)` ?

Comment: so in the list that i have passed in squares , i want it to go through each number individualy. so exp: def square(2):  return 2(2*2)  witch will give me an answer of 8

Comment: Concatenation isn't multiplication in Python. Writing `2` and `(x * x)` next to each other doesn't mean multiply them.

Comment: Also note that `int(x)` doesn't do anything. It converts the value of x to an integer, but doesn't store it anywhere. Maybe you'ld want `x = int(x)` ?

Comment: error means that somewhere in code you assigned value to varaible `int` - ie. `int = 2` - so now it can't access function `int()` - check `print(int)` and `print(type(int))`

Answer (score 3):

here's a fix to your `square` function (you were missing a `*` operator)

```
def square(x):
    int(x)
    return 2*(x * x)
```

however, according to your function name I'm guessing you wanted the function to return the square of x:

```
2 --> 4
3 --> 9
4 --> 16
```

in that case, here's also a bug fix:

```
def square(x):
   return x**2
```

Answer (score 2):

The line `2(x * x)` is causing python to treat the integer 2 as a function with arguments `x*x`, and hence the error `"TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"`

```
In [16]: x = 1                                                                                                 

In [17]: 2(x*x)                                                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-14e610e542ba> in <module>
----> 1 2(x*x)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

To square a number, you need `x**2` instead, or perhaps `pow(x, 2)`using the [pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) builtin

```
def square(x):
    int(x)
    return x**2
```

Comment: thanks but i dont understand how python is taking 2 as a function. i feel like this is a python subject that i can probably read somewhere. but how should i look for it in google.

Comment: 2 is actually an object of type int. `In [23]: type(2)                                                                                               Out[23]: int` as in python, integers are treated as an object and you also see that in the error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `2(x * x)` statement. In the Python programming language, we need to explicitly mention all the operators in expressions. Like, the statement should be `2*(x*x)` and when you use rounded brackets, you are actually calling the function.

Also, the above program can be reduced to,

```
In [54]: list(map(lambda no: int(no)**2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
Out[54]: [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```